# Flutter: Partially overlapping buttons that can switch overlapping on tap

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, widget, stack

I am trying to create a layout of two elevated buttons as below screen shots. One button is partially overlapping other button on the right side. When button on the right is tapped then it will partially overlap the button on left.

I can do it using stack but that will require a lot playing around with the positions.

I am wondering if someone could point me to the right direction on how to achieve this layout.

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

Regards,

Jamal